# do I post to a model that is available as a list?

Tags: html, .net, forms, post, model-view-controller

First of all, hello to everyone. I'm new to .net mvc. I have a listing page. There are students listed. So far, so good. Here students' grades need to be entered and all grades must be saved at the same time. However, since the model is kept as a list, I cannot bring up the area where the data will be saved.

for example:

```
 @ Html.EditorFor (model => model.note, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
```

I can not bring the quality of note when I say model1 here.

and so I can't post. I'm having trouble with the html section.

My html code:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineBasvuru.Entity.ViewModel.Exam>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ExamSave", "Exam", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "examID" }))
    {
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>
                        ChildrenID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Note
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               @for (int i=0; i<Model.Count(); i++)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.childrenID[i])
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @ Html.EditorFor (model => model.note, new 
                        {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>

        </table>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the grades list inside the model list, You can use foreach loop for the Exam Model and then again foreach loop over the grades (or) you can use it as array model.grades[i]. And any controls like textbox, text editor, text area which gets user input is sent to the server in post request, so you can get the values entered by user as exam list in the post method in the controller